# Weird Dropdown Behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I've a very confusing issue where the li with class 'search is moved down under the dropdown box when it is shown, all other li's stay in place where they should be, any suggestions?

It's only when the dropdown is displayed otherwise the 'search' li appears and works as expected.

http://i43.tinypic.com/2z686md.png

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Eab/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="first"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">CATEGORIES<span class="arrow"></span></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="error">Unable to find category listings.</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="search">
        SEARCH:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="search">
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.nav .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    width: 98%;
    height: 130px;
    margin-top: 38px;
    margin-left: -2%;
    padding: 2%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #0F2F54;
    opacity: 0.95;
    z-index: 1;
}
ul.nav li .dropdown {
    display: none;
}
ul.nav li:hover .dropdown {
    display: block; 
}
.dropdown ul.category li a {
    width: 23%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-right: none;
}
.dropdown ul.category li a:hover {
    background: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
ul.nav li.search {
    float: right;
    height: 32px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding: 6px 10px 0 10px;
    border-left: 1px #336198 solid;
    border-right: 1px #336198 solid;
    display: inline;
}
ul.nav li.search input {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("ul.nav .dropdown").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).prev().css('background', '#0F2F54');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).prev().css('background', '');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your dropdown `div` is within the `li` so it is simply `displaying` itself before the 2nd `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix for your code, just making the dropdown class as `absolute` will not affect other elements on the page.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Eab/5/)

Answer (score 0):

make the position of dropdown `absolute`;
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/semir/G2Eab/3/)

Answer (score 0):

in your css `.dropdown` class has `position:relative` that means it aligns itself relative to its adjacent elements changing it to absolute will make `.dropdown` align as per absolute position.

```
ul.nav .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    width: 98%;
    height: 130px;
    margin-top: 38px;
    margin-left: -2%;
    padding: 2%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #0F2F54;
    opacity: 0.95;
    z-index: 1;
}
```